# Por que esta função retorna object e não array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Precisei converter a string em lista/*array*, fiz a seguinte função:

`function s_for_l(s){var string = new Array(); for (let i of s) {string.push(i)}; return string}`

mas ela só retorna `object`, não `array` como o esperado.

Comment: Mostra o exemplo do retorno, que aqui só retorna array essa sua função

Comment: É verdade o que @Maniero disse. Só que daí os valores estão em array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O fato de você esperar não significa que deve acontecer. O esperado para mim que li a especificação da linguagem é retornar `object` mesmo.

Veja a [lista de tipos que o JavaScript possui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures). Onde está o `array`? Não resultar um tipo que não existe. Então se não é um tipo numérico, texto ou um símbolo especial só pode ser um `object`.

Os tipos `object` podem ter especializações, uma dessas especializações já existente é o *array*, mas isso não é o tipo do valor ou da variável naquele momento. Um *array* em JS é só um objeto como uma forma específica, por exemplo tem uma propriedade `lenght` para determinar quantos elementos tem dentro desse objeto. E tem outros métodos que fazem operações específicas para essas especialização de `object` que chamamos de *array*.

Mas tipo `Array`, existe só em outras linguagens, geralmente de tipagem estática.

O problema não está nesse código se pegar o tipo de um *array* escrito normalmente o tipo também será `object`.

```js
console.log(typeof [1, 2, 3]);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Typing/ArrayType.js).

Answer (score 0):

Aproveitando a resposta do colega  [Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero), a sua função já retorna um `array`, porém o tipo da variável retornada é `object`

```
function s_for_l(s){
    var string = new Array(); 
    for (let i of s) string.push(i)
    return string
}
```

Dados do retorno:

**Valor**

```
 console.log(convert('Carlos'));

 [ 'C', 'a', 'r', 'l', 'o', 's' ]
```

Tipo

```
console.log(typeof convert('Carlos'));
object
```

Vide exemplo

```js
function convert (s) {
    const string = new Array()
    for(let i of s) string.push(i)
    return string
} 

console.log('Valor',convert('Carlos'));
console.log('Tipo',typeof convert('Carlos'));
```